# Calculate same day start/end dates as 0 days if another occurrence already exists

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I have a query where there are instances where a "phase" starts and ends on the same day - this is calculated as 1 day.  If, however, another "phase" starts and ends on the same day against the same ref. no. and period no., then I'd like to calculate this as 0 days.

Example:

```
**Ref.  Period.  Phase  StDt        EndDt**
013     3        KAA    01/01/16    01/01/16  - This is one day
013     3        TAA    02/01/16    03/01/16  - this is 2 days    
013     3        KAT    01/01/16    01/01/16  - **would like this to be counted as 0 day**
013     3        TTA    04/04/16    04/04/16  - this is one day
```

I would like this unique calculation to be done in the data grouped by Ref. And Period numbers.  This is a tricky one....

Thanks

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide the results that you want  (3) What is your date format?

Comment: Date format is Date+Time.  The results I want are in the table above.  Basically, for every ref/period, if there are more than one phases which start and end on the same date, I'd like just one of the phases to be counted as one day and the others as 0 days. Phase code could be unique or not.  The unique identifiers to group by are Ref and Period.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below did the trick! Basically, I'm using count aggregate to count the number of instances where phases start and end on the same day PER Ref and period.  Then, for any where there are more than 1, I just use simple case statments to count the first one as 1 and any subsequent ones as 0. I'm creating the below as a subquery in the joins as a left outer join:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      (SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT Period, Ref, 
CONVERT(date, PhaseStartDate) AS stdt, CONVERT(date, PhaseEndDate) AS enddt, 
COUNT(*) 
                                               AS NoOfSameDayPhases, 
MIN(PhaseSequence) AS FirstPhSeq
                        FROM          Phases AS Phases_1
                        WHERE      (CONVERT(date, PhaseStartDate) = 
CONVERT(date, PhaseEndDate))
                        GROUP BY VoidPeriod, Ref, CONVERT(date, 
PhaseStartDate), CONVERT(date, PhaseEndDate)) AS SameDayPH ON CONVERT(date, 
                  PhaseEndDate) = SameDayPH.enddt AND CONVERT(date, 
PhaseStartDate) = SameDayPH.stdt AND 
                  VoidPeriod = SameDayPH.VoidPeriod AND SameDayPH.Ref = 
VoidPhases.Ref
```

Comment: You should remove TOP (100) PERCENT.  That is ignored by SQL Server after 2000.  If you really must return an ordered result, you can use a number.

Answer (score 0):

This expression should work on the SSRS side:

```
=IIF(Fields!StartDate.Value=Fields!EndDate.Value AND Fields!Phase.Value <> LOOKUPSET(Fields!StartDate.Value &"_" & Fields!EndDate.Value,Fields!StartDate.Value & "_" & Fields!EndDate.Value,Fields!Phase.Value,"DatasetName").GetValue(0),0,DATEDIFF("D",Fields!StartDate.Value,Fields!EndDate.Value)+1)
```

It will return a value of 1 for the first phase returned by the dataset.  If the phase-date range combinations are not unique within the grouping, this will not work as written, but you should be able to modify accordingly.

Also, if the rows are sorted differently between SSRS and the dataset, it may not be the first row that appears that gets the 1.

Comment: Unfortunately, the phases could be unique or not per Ref. and period no.

Comment: Could you please explain the logic/principle behind this approach?  thanks.

Comment: Sure.  The Lookupset function is returning a list of phases from the dataset specified where there is a row with a date range matches the current row.  GetValue(0) limits that list to the first occurrence.  If the phase of the current row does not match the phase of that first occurrence, and the start date and end date are the same, the IIF returns zero, else it calculates the days.  You can use any value/combination of values in place of phase that would be unique by date range per ref and period, but you didn't offer any alternative in the provided dataset.

Comment: I just realized the wording in my original answer was misleading with regard to what must be unique.  Just edited for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. 
I am assuming that you are using TSQl (Not sure a you have also tagged SQL.

```
;WITH cte_result(ID,Ref, Period,Phase,StDt,EndDt) AS
(
SELECT 1,'013' ,3,'KAA',CAST('01/01/16'AS DATETIME),CAST('01/01/16'AS DATETIME) UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'013' ,3,'TAA','01/02/16','01/03/16' UNION ALL 
SELECT 3,'013' ,3,'KAT','01/01/16','01/01/16' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'013' ,3,'TTA','04/04/16','04/04/16')
,cte_PreResult AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(StDt AS DATE), CAST(EndDt AS DATE) ORDER BY ID) AS [Order],
    Ref,
    Period,
    Phase,
    StDt,
    EndDt
FROM cte_result
)
SELECT Ref,
    Period,
    Phase,
    StDt,
    EndDt,
    CASE 
        WHEN [Order] <> 1
            THEN '0 Day(s)'
        ELSE CAST(DATEDIFF(dd, StDt, EndDt) + 1 AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Day(s)'
        END AS Comment
FROM cte_PreResult
```

If there is no ID column then select some column to order by, probably Phase so replace ID with Phase as here **ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StDt,EndDt ORDER BY ID) AS [Order]**, if there is no candidate column to order by then try this

```
;WITH cte_result(ID,Ref, Period,Phase,StDt,EndDt) AS
(
SELECT 1,'013' ,3,'KAA',CAST('01/01/16'AS DATETIME),CAST('01/01/16'AS DATETIME) UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'013' ,3,'TAA','01/02/16','01/03/16' UNION ALL 
SELECT 3,'013' ,3,'KAT','01/01/16','01/01/16' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'013' ,3,'TTA','04/04/16','04/04/16')
,cte_PreResult AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(StDt AS DATE), CAST(EndDt AS DATE) ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [Order],
    Ref,
    Period,
    Phase,
    StDt,
    EndDt
FROM cte_result
)
SELECT Ref,
    Period,
    Phase,
    StDt,
    EndDt,
    CASE 
        WHEN [Order] <> 1
            THEN '0 Day(s)'
        ELSE CAST(DATEDIFF(dd, StDt, EndDt) + 1 AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Day(s)'
        END AS Comment
FROM cte_PreResult
```